# Kotlin Design Pattern, Problem with Observer

Tags: kotlin, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I tried different ways, but the outcome is still not the way it should be. I have to create a small weather app in Kotlin with some Design Patterns.

```
interface Sensor {
    fun getTemperature() : Float
}

class RandomSensor () : Sensor {
    override fun getTemperature(): Float {
        var randomTemp : Double = Random.nextDouble (0.0, 40.00)
        return randomTemp.toFloat()
    }
}

class Thermometer (var sensor: Sensor)  {

    var newTemp = this.sensor.getTemperature()

    val tempwerte = mutableListOf<Float>(newTemp)

    val observers = mutableListOf<TemperaturObserver>()

    fun register(observer:TemperaturObserver) {
        observers.add(observer)
    }

    fun remove(observer: TemperaturObserver) {
        observers.remove(observer)
    }

    fun dataChanged() {
        observers.forEach {it.update(newTemp)}
    }

    fun messen() {
        var n = 100
        for (i in 0 until n) {
            newTemp = this.sensor.getTemperature()

            if(i != n) {
                dataChanged()
                tempwerte.add(newTemp)
            }
        }
    }
    fun getTenlastItems () = tempwerte.takeLast(10)
    fun getHundredItems () = tempwerte.take (100)
}
```

the observer "weatherReport" should collect 10 items (temperature), print them and collect the next 10 items and so on

My solution

```
interface TemperaturObserver  {
    fun update (newTemp : Float)
}

class WeatherReport (private var station : Thermometer) : TemperaturObserver {
    override fun update (newTemp: Float) {
        var newList = mutableListOf<Float>(newTemp)

        while (newList.size != 10) {
        newList.add(newTemp)
        }
        println(newList)

    }

}
```

creates this output

```
[40.0, 40.0, 40.0, 40.0, 40.0, 40.0, 40.0, 40.0, 40.0, 40.0]
[24.0, 24.0, 24.0, 24.0, 24.0, 24.0, 24.0, 24.0, 24.0, 24.0]
```

etc....

Any ideas how to solve the problem? It should be like that:

```
[21.0, 23.0, 0.0, 1.0, 35.0, 4.0, 14.0, 3.0, 16.0, 36.0]
[22.0, 27.0, 21.0, 32.0, 20.0, 31.0, 37.0, 33.0, 24.0, 2.0]
```

etc...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The observed output is explained by the fact that you create a new list in `WeatherReport.update` method and fill it ten times with the same `newTemp` value.

If you want instead to collect values and print them out once ten values are collected, you should create a list once, then populate it one value at a time and check if it has reached ten values:

```
class WeatherReport(private var station: Thermometer) : TemperaturObserver {
    val observedValues = mutableListOf<Float>()
    override fun update(newTemp: Float) {
        observedValues.add(newTemp)
        if (observedValues.size >= 10) {
            println(observedValues)
            observedValues.clear()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works fine